# SSL module issue while installing pandas on RHEL6

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, openssl

Did anyone got the issues while  installing with pandas..
I also tried configuring with `./configure --with-openssl="/usr/bin/openssl"`

```
# /opt/bin/python3  -m pip install numpy scipy matplotlib ipython jupyter pandas sympy nose
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting numpy
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/numpy/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/numpy/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/numpy/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/numpy/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/numpy/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/numpy/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/numpy/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

Comment: "I also tried configuring" - configuring what? Python? Have you rebuilt and reinstalled Python after reconfiguring it?

Comment: @ForceBru, as i mentioned reconfigure with ssl path and yes rebuild it with `make & make install`

Comment: Wait, but the argument to `--with-openssl` [is supposed to be a directory](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b3dd5cd4a36877c473417fd7b3358843dcf8e647/configure#L1579), not the `openssl` _executable_. See examples of SSL directories [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b3dd5cd4a36877c473417fd7b3358843dcf8e647/m4/ax_check_openssl.m4#L66).

Comment: @ForceBru, Yes.. my bad, i have done with the Directory itself.

Comment: It works fine with the python3.6